# How to use strategy pattern in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I am making some rest calls in my code based upon the value in a variable. Each of these rest calls takes a different number of parameters but the response remains the same.

```
if (type=="Membership"){
    reponse=await claimRepo.findDetailsByMembersip(memberNumber)
}
else if (type=="Claim"){
    reponse=await claimRepo.findDetailsByClaim(claimNumber)
}
else if (type=="Date"){
    reponse=await claimRepo.findDetailsByDate(date)
}
```

Now inside the claimRepo class

```
async findDetailsByMembersip(memberNumber){
    const data=requests.get('someurl')//make the call
    return {
        data,
        statusCode
    }
}

async findDetailsByClaim(claimNumber){
    const data=requests.get('someurl')//make the call
    return {
        data,
        statusCode
    }
}

async findDetailsByDate(date){
    const data=requests.get('someurl')//make the call
    return {
        data,
        statusCode
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of these if-else blocks and implement this using the strategy pattern ?

Comment: Have you tried to search for _"strategy pattern javascript"_? I get many results with explanation and code snippets.

Comment: "*Each of these rest calls takes a different number of parameters but the response remains the same.*" doesn't sound like the case for a strategy pattern - typically different strategies still have the exact same interface. You can probably just pass all and let the strategy determine what it uses or not but it's a bit of a kludge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code example mentioned below for **Strategy Pattern**. You can modify code according to your need;

```
function findDetailsByMembersip(memberNumber) {
    this.call = (memberNumber) => {
        const data = 1; //requests.get('someurl')//make the call
        return {
            data,
            memberNumber
        }
    }
}

function findDetailsByClaim(claimNumber) {
    this.call = (claimNumber) => {
        const data = 2; //requests.get('someurl')//make the call
        return {
            data,
            claimNumber
        }
    }
}

function findDetailsByDate(date) {
    this.call = (date) => {
        const data = 3; //requests.get('someurl')//make the call
        return {
            data,
            date
        }
    }
}

function StrategyManager() {
    this.strategy = null;

    this.setStrategy = (strategy) => {
        this.strategy  = strategy;
    }

    this.call = (args) => {
        return this.strategy.call(args);
    }
}

const strategy = new StrategyManager();
const membership = new findDetailsByMembersip();
const claim = new findDetailsByClaim();
const dates = new findDetailsByDate();

strategy.setStrategy(membership);
console.log(strategy.call('membership'));

strategy.setStrategy(claim);
console.log(strategy.call('claims'));

strategy.setStrategy(dates);
console.log(strategy.call('dates'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an obj (acting as a dictionary): keys are the type (the `if` condition) and values the references to the function to call

```js
const fnsByType = {
  "Membership": claimRepo.findDetailsByMembersip,
  "Claim": claimRepo.findDetailsByClaim
  "Date": claimRepo.findDetailsByDate
}
```

then you might:

```js
const doCall = async (type, param) => fnsByType[type](param)
```

Note that you need to provide accurate params to `doCall` function.

```
doCall("Membership", memberNumber).then(...)
doCall("Claim", claimNumber).then(...)
doCall("Date", date).then(...)
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between `claimRepo.findDetailsByMembersip(memberNumber)` and `doCall("Membership", memberNumber)` - you've introduced a level of abstraction for a double dispatch but there is no actual other thing you can use here. The method/key and parameter still are still interlinked and vary with each other. The end result is the same only masked slightly through the level of abstraction.

Comment: Answering the question "_is there a way to get rid of these if-else blocks_"